# How to store the output of my customized function in R?

Tags: r, function, rename

I want to build my function to change the column name.

```
x1 = c(1:5)
x2 = c(6:10)
x = data.frame(
  X1 = x1,
  X2 = x2
)

myFunction = function(x) {
  x <- rename(x, "newX1" = "X1")
  x <- rename(x, "newX2" = "X2")
  newX <- x
  return(newX)
}

print(myFunction(x))
```

output is below:

```
  newX1 newX2
1     1     6
2     2     7
3     3     8
4     4     9
5     5    10
```

I can see the result that I intended, but the output does not store as data in my memory.
I want to do the next process using the output (data) of the function.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `y <- myFunction(x)`.

Comment: @Park OMG! It is so simple way. Thanks a lot!!! :D

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary code too, this does the same: `myFunction <- function(x) {rename(x, "newX1" = "X1", "newX2" = "X2")}` and arguably, it shouldn't even be a custom function, you could just use `y <- rename(...`

Comment: To elaborate on Park's answer: R uses "call by value". This means that input arguments are copied and changing them in the function body has no effect on the passed variable.

Comment: @rg255 When I do data cleansing, I thought that function because the data have many columns that need rename process. Then I can use the function by putting each filename in x. If you have a better idea, please let me know. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you mean you have a lot of data.frames where you want to do the same renaming? e.g. `df1 <- rename(df1, "newX" = "x", "newY" = "y"); df2 <- rename(df2, "newX" = "x", "newY" = "y"); df3 <- rename(df3, "newX" = "x", "newY" = "y"); ...`

Comment: @rg255 Oh, I misunderstood your first comment. I could not recognize the `{   }` part in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of code that you do not need in your attempt - essentially you have just created a wrapper for the `rename()` function without adding much to it. You could just do

```
rename(x, "newX1" = "x1", "newX2" = "x2"))
```

To get it to assign ot the object, you can then do

```
x <- rename(x, "newX1" = "x1", "newX2" = "x2"))
```

Or

```
assign("x", rename(x, "newX1" = "x1", "newX2" = "x2"))
```

From your comments, it seems you have many data.frames where you want to do this same renaming, you could automate that with a `for` loop

```
# Exmaple datasets
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- df4 <- df5 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 6:10)
# Define datasets to rename
datasets_to_rename <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
# Rename the selected datasets
for(i in datasets_to_rename){
  assign(i, rename(get(i), "newX1" = "x1", "newX2" = "x2"))
}
```

You could make this more automatic if you want to do this for all data.frames in the global environment with

```
for(i in names(Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv)))){
  assign(i, rename(get(i), "newX1" = "x1", "newX2" = "x2"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this answer! :D